# Sending multiple values as parameter to Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

net application. In this i came across one situation in which user has to send some parameters to Oracle stored procedure and the values that are passed to these parameters come from multi select listboxes and procedure does a search using these values. I couldn't find a way to send these values to stored procedure generally i'm attaching parameter to stored proc in asp side by using the statement like

```
storedProc.AddString("state", state);
```

but there is no method to send these multi selected values. Like i i have to send multiple selected values for state as one parameter, city as one parameter like that. One way which i found is to concatenate these values as a string separated by comma and split the string in database side.

Comment: "One way which i found is to concatenate these values as a string separated by comma and split the string in database side." So what's wrong with that? You need to ask a question, don't just state a problem.

Comment: I don't know if it will work, long shot, did you tried to pass it as an array?

Comment: i tried to pass as list but as i'm working on oracle there is no data type for stored proc parameter which supports list but there is one in Mysql which is Structure type